Essentia models in ML.NET fail to predict
I'm trying to predict using the Essentia discogs_track_embeddings-effnet-bs64 model with ML.NET. I've tried both using tensorflow and onnx, but when I try to predict anything I'm stuck with
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ML.Data.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.ML.Data.dll
Splitter/consolidator worker encountered exception while consuming source data

Currently, I'm using onnx so the rest of this will be stack traces and code from that attempt.
Full Call Stack:
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.DataViewUtils.Splitter.Batch.SetAll(OutPipe[] pipes)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.DataViewUtils.Splitter.Cursor.MoveNextCore()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.RootCursorBase.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.ColumnCursorExtensions.<GetColumnArrayDirect>d__4`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 122

on the line: var embeddingColumn = transformedData.GetColumn<float[]>("embeddings").ToList();
onnx loading and predicting code:
Console.WriteLine($"[+] Loading Model");
var mlContext = new MLContext();

// load melspectrogram data into pipeline
var modelPath = "discogs_track_embeddings-effnet-bs64-1.onnx";
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(
    modelFile: modelPath,
    fallbackToCpu: true
);
IDataView mockData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List<ModelInput>() { new ModelInput() });
var model = pipeline.Fit(mockData);

var schema = model.Transform(mockData).Schema;
Console.WriteLine("[*] Model Schema:");
foreach (var column in schema)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Column Name: {column.Name}, Column Type: {column.Type}");
}


List<ModelOutput> allPredictions = new List<ModelOutput>();

foreach (var segment in melSpectrogram)
{
    var seg = MelSpectrogramGenerator.ConvertToFloat(segment);
    
    var data = new ModelInput
    {
        Melspectrogram = seg
    };
    IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new [] { data });
    var transformedData = model.Transform(dataView);

    // Retrieve the embeddings
    var embeddingColumn = transformedData.GetColumn<float[]>("embeddings").ToList();
    foreach (var value in embeddingColumn.First())
    {
        Console.Write($"{value} ");
    }
    //allPredictions.Add(scoredData.);
    Console.WriteLine("Wheee");
}


public class ModelInput
{
    [VectorType(64, 128, 96)]
    [ColumnName("melspectrogram")]
    public float[,,] Melspectrogram { get; set; }
    public ModelInput()
    {
        Melspectrogram = new float[64, 128, 96];
    }
}

// Define output schema
public class ModelOutput
{
    [VectorType(64, 512)]
    [ColumnName("embeddings")]
    public float[,] Embeddings { get; set; }
    public ModelOutput()
    {
        Embeddings = new float[64, 512];
    }
}

Currently on Microsoft.ML 3.0.1, Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Managed 1.18.0
I've checked and my data has no NaN in it, and none of my variables are Null. I'm super lost and unsure how to fix this or even move forward with troubleshooting.

For anyone who gets stuck on this after me:
ML.NET (as of 3.0) doesn't seem to support multidimensional input/output arrays, so models that use it from tensorflow need to be flattened!
Use the VectorType attribute to tell ML.NET what the flattened float arrays look like:
public class ModelInput
{
    [VectorType(64, 128, 96)]
    [ColumnName("melspectrogram")]
    public float[] Melspectrogram { get; set; }
}

// Define output schema
public class ModelOutput
{
    [VectorType(64, 512)]
    [ColumnName("embeddings")]
    public float[] Embeddings { get; set; }
}

Then Flatten your arrays! These are specifically fit for my usecase, yours may be different:
public static float[] FlattenArray(float[,,] inputArray)
{
    int dim1 = inputArray.GetLength(0);
    int dim2 = inputArray.GetLength(1);
    int dim3 = inputArray.GetLength(2);

    float[] flatArray = new float[dim1 * dim2 * dim3];

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dim3; k++)
            {
                flatArray[index++] = inputArray[i, j, k];
            }
        }
    }

    return flatArray;
}
public static float[,] UnflattenArray(float[] flatArray)
{
    int dim1 = 64;
    int dim2 = 512;

    float[,] outputArray = new float[dim1, dim2];

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++)
        {
            outputArray[i, j] = flatArray[index++];
        }
    }

    return outputArray;
}

